# Cannot read property 'Qa' of undefined×

Tags: google-visualization

On some of my users' browsers, Google Visualization is returning this error.

`Cannot read property 'Qa' of undefined×`

Is there any idea as to what this might mean? I cannot replicate the error and there is very little available on this particular message.

Comment: will you please share the code?